# i have got session_start() error whenever i put my website online i am using godaddy

Tags: php, session, warnings

i have got this errors while running online

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/home/content/41/3604341/tmp/sess_fql4o6dd9obebt95i23lkvs3f7, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /home/content/41/3604341/html/computermall/index.php on line 1
```

and this is my index.php topmost lines

```
<?php session_start();
if(isset($_COOKIE['uniqueID'])=='')
{
$uniquenum = rand(1000, 10000);
setcookie('uniqueID',$uniquenum,time() + (86400 * 7)); // 86400 = 1 day
}
$time = microtime();
$time = explode(' ', $time);
$time = $time[1] + $time[0];
$start = $time;
?>
```

Comment: can you create new file and write: `<?php session_start(); ?>`

Comment: Try creating a (by the web server writable) directory called `tmp` in `/home/content/41/3604341`.

Comment: can you please explain me why i need to create a new file?

Comment: @tech02 You need to create an empty directory for the web server to save sessions in. That is done to allow the web server to restart without every user being kicked out of the system and have to re-login. The error message says that it tries to write a file called `/home/content/41/3604341/tmp/sess_fql4o6dd9obebt95i23lkvs3f7`, and since `/home/content/41/3604341` exists, it looks like it's the `tmp` subdirectory that is missing.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson  you right,tmp was missing..thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Header information error fix**

```
ob_start();
```

before session_start();

**and make a writable directory as Jochem said:**

```
tmp in /home/content/41/3604341.
```